# Visual Studio 2022 - Currently file not found in WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I've an old and a new clean WPF project, .NET6, C# with Visual Studio 2022 17.9.2
And for both I get the error, that the App.xaml and MainWindow.xaml could not be opened.

Is this a bug of the current VST version?
Or do I have to change something fundamentally? The "old" project is from last year and built properly all the time - but a new create C#, WPF project shows the same errors.

Or is .NET6 not supported anymore under the newest VST updates?

[image]

Comment: Works on my machine

Comment: And the files are definitely present in your project directory, I suppose?

Comment: The files are present. Can be opened in other editors. And even in a complete new WPF project that error occurs.

Comment: If it happens in a brand new project, you have some sort of installation/configuration issue.  Try repairing your install